# How to make a pyramid out of asterisks

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I'm trying to create a program that using range, outputs a triangle made of asterisks. For example:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

I can't really figure out how to do it though, all I have right now is:

```
number=10
for i in range(0,number,-1):
    number="*"
    print i
```

I know it's obviously wrong, but I can't figure out how to do it. Some help would be appreciated, and remember that I have to use `range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close. Let me edit your own code to point out where you went wrong instead of writing my own code.Few things about range are :

- `range(start,stop,steps)` is the syntax. When you say `range(0,100)` then keep in mind that it'll take the values from 0 to 99 (total count is 100 but not including 100).
- the default value of start and steps is 0 and 1 respectively.So `range(0,10) = range(0,10,1)` and also if you have to start from 0 then no need to specify it again. So now  `range(0,10) = range(0,10,1) = range(10)`
- steps can be negative value only if start value is greater than stop value. *for this reason your code didn't work as you expected*

> ```
> number=10                    ## assigning 10 to number
> for i in range(0,number,-1): ## remove -1
>     number="*"               ## totally unnecessary 
>     print i
> ```

```
number=10
for i in range(0,number,1):  ## no need to mention the steps by default it'll be 1
    print "*"*i              ## * is multiplied i times and printed.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
number = 10
for i in range(number):
    print "*" * i
```

Remember that for any string, the multiplication operation will just concatenate copies of that string. For example, `"a" * 5 = "aaaaa"`. That's the key to this puzzle.

Comment: looking at the handcrafted "pyramid" of the OP, I'd rather say `print "*" * (i+1)`

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do

```
for i in range(1,11): #11 because it stops before the second number
    print '*' * i
```

you could also do something like this:

```
 s= '' #initialize our string
 for i in range(10):
     s+='*' #add an asterisk for each iteration
     print s #print our one asterisk richer string
```

Note that "foo += bar" is really just shorthand for "foo = foo+bar"

They are functionally the same.